# Prove $X$ is infinite iff $X$ is equinumerous with a proper subset of itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Below is a proof of this statement(part (iii))
[image]

My question is, for the first direction(the first paragraph of (iii)), why it is enough to prove for every $n\in\omega$, if $f: n\to n$ is injective, then $f$ is surjective. I don't really understand what this statement represents. Doesn't this equivalent to "if $n\leq n$, then $n\geq n$"? Further, why can we conclude $g$ is surjective by given $g$ restricted to $n$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking in terms of cardinals is only helpful once you've formally established all the properties needed here.

To prove that if $f\colon n\to n$ is injective, then $f$ is surjective as well, means that if $A\subseteq n$ is any subset of size $n$, then $A=n$. So, $n$ is not equinumerous to any of its proper subsets.

So, once you've also shown that there is an injective $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ which is not surjective, and that if $A$ is infinite, then $\omega\leq|A|$, you can conclude that a set is infinite if and only if it is Dedekind-infinite: if it is infinite, we have shown there is such a function; if it is finite, we have shown that there is none.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Now I understand what that statement mean. Could you explain why $g$ is surjective?

Comment: Which part is problematic? Have you tried an example of a function to see how that argument plays out?

Comment: So we have $g$ restricted to $n$ is surjective, and $g$ restricted to $n^\dagger$ is injective. This means $g$ must map $n$ to $n$ which makes it surjective?

Comment: Pretty much. Yes.